# "mean for" or "be meant for"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I read [this](http://lovefreenovels.com/Fiction/This_Is_Falling/page_43.html)

> I know I shouldn’t read it. I should just delete it or not look at it
>   and write her back quickly, letting her know she sent me something
>   **meant for** someone else.

I looked up there are both "mean for" and "be meant for" phrase.

[mean for](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mean+for)

[be meant for](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-meant-for)

But even the example from "mean for" has a "be".

> Sorry, my question **was** actually **meant for** Mrs. Roberts.

I wonder if there always would be a "be" in there? Why does the first senten above omit a "be"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice).

"My question was actually meant for Mrs. Roberts" is a way of saying "I meant this question for Mrs. Roberts."

Comment: But I think "she sent me something meant for someone else" is also passive. "something was meant for someone else."

Comment: Malvolio is correct.  It's just passive voice.  Just remember its preferred to use the active voice. Passive voice deemphasizes the subject by stating actions received by vs. performed by the subject. This also points away from subject as most important making sentence vague or confusing. Active is clearer; direct; forthright.   "Be meant for" "that's meant for" serves to make the sentence passive. Emphasizes the object as more important than the subject in the sentence.  Both active and passive are grammatically correct; but, advice is to use active voice over passive.

Comment: @Zhang -- in "something meant for someone else", "meant" is a gerund used as part of a adjectival phrase.  Compare "something borrowed, something blue" or "half-eaten sandwich".  The gerunds "borrowed" and "eaten" means the noun _had been_ the object of the verb.